# programs to process css files? for instance remove all media queries

Tags: css

From a mobile-first static CSS file (minified) I'd like to remove all `@media` queries, so that the site will always show as on mobile, is there any command/tool to process `(.min).css` files in that way? (I'm looking around but found nothing yet)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind,

I found and used [postcss-filter-mq](https://github.com/simeydotme/postcss-filter-mq) that removed the media queries correctly but something else is wrong with the website.

For anyone who could be interested, initialize a npm project

```
npm init
```

Install postcss and the media query filter

```
npm install --save-dev postcss postcss-filter-mq
```

add/edit `index.js`

```
var postcss = require("postcss"),
    filtermq = require("postcss-filter-mq"),
    fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('input.min.css', function(err, css) {    
    postcss([ filtermq({invert: true, keepBaseRules: true}) ])
        .process(css, { from: "input.min.css", to: "output.min.css" })
        .then(function (result) {
            fs.writeFileSync("output.min.css", result.css);
            if ( result.map ) fs.writeFileSync("output.min.css.map", result.map);
        });
});
```

run with `node index.js`, input/output filenames wired in the code (`input.min.css` `output.min.css` ...)